# Pandas: Edit index values and re-groupby, according to new values

Tags: python, pandas

I have my index set to 'ShiftId' which looks like this: 201912240 (the date followed by a 0 or 1 that indicates day or night shift). I have my df grouped by index values that return, as expected, something like this:

```
           col1 col2
201912240  NaN  23
201912241  44   75
201912250  12   NaN
201912251  46   91
```

I want to regroup this dataframe to take the mean of each day (ignoring NaN values), then it will look like this

```
           col1 col2
20191224   44   49
20191225   29   91
```

But I can't get the current index values to be grouped. I have tried

```
    days_frame.index = days_frame.index.map(lambda x: str(x)[:-1])
    days_frame.groupby(days_frame.index).mean()
```

But this doesn't even change anything in the df?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution for me working, maybe you forget assign output to variable like `df` here:

```
days_frame.index = days_frame.index.map(lambda x: str(x)[:-1])
df = days_frame.groupby(days_frame.index).mean()
print (df)
          col1  col2
20191224  44.0  49.0
20191225  29.0  91.0
```

Another solution rename index first and then use `mean` per index values:

```
df = days_frame.rename(lambda x: str(x)[:-1]).mean(level=0)
print (df)
          col1  col2
20191224  44.0  49.0
20191225  29.0  91.0
```

Or convert index to strings, remove last value and pass to `groupby` with aggregate `mean`:

```
df = days_frame.groupby(days_frame.index.astype(str).str[:-1]).mean()
print (df)
          col1  col2
20191224  44.0  49.0
20191225  29.0  91.0
```

EDIT:

If want avoid truncating all columns without `A` column use this solution before write to file:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[.41,1.5,.2,2,.3],
                   'B':['a'] * 5,
                   'C':[3,4,5,4,5],
                   'D':[1.0,3,4,5,6]})

cols = df.columns.difference(['A'])

df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: '%.0f' % x if isinstance(x, (float, int)) else x)
print (df)

      A  B  C  D
0  0.41  a  3  1
1  1.50  a  4  3
2  0.20  a  5  4
3  2.00  a  4  5
4  0.30  a  5  6
```

Comment: Can I ask you another question in here? It's mostly relevant

Comment: @LlewellynHattingh - Sure, come on ;)

Comment: pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.0f' % x). I am using this to avoid getting truncated values in html file. It is very necessary, the problem I have is that it rounds ALL columns (which for the most part is fine), but there is one specific column that I don't want this to happen... because otherwise I only see 0 instead of 0.322 (which is very important information).. Thanx @jezrael

Comment: Thanx, it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.. I am working in a big .py file.. is there maybe any prerequisites for this to work? Or something I am missing?

Comment: @LlewellynHattingh - Do you think it not working for huge data file? Is possible test it for some smaller file, e.g. for first  100 rows?

Comment: Will do thanx -jezrael (also, you personally have helped me before so I assume you are very familiar with stack overflow.. will I always only be allowed to ask a question every 90 minutes?)

Comment: @LlewellynHattingh - It is only for new users, this 90 minutes. I think after some time and some reputions it should be better, no 90 minutes.

Comment: Also, I got your code to work. Thanx for all the help!!